# How to persist two object that have *same* objecte reference into them?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Imagine this scenario: I have an entity with some related entities that I want to update follow some logic.

```
public function updateRelated($foo) {
  foreach($foo->getBars() as $bar) {
    //modify bar attributes based on some logic
    $this->entity_manager->persist($bar); //entity manager was correctly instantiated
  }
}
```

`$foo` is an object composed in that way

```
public function retrieveFoo() {
 $foo = new Foo();
 $bar = new Bar();
 $foobar = $this->entity_manager->getRepository('MyProject:FooBar');
 $bar->setFooBar($fooBar);
 $foo->setBar($bar);

 return $foo;
}
```

this `retrieveFoo()` function is called multiple times than, I call `updateRelated()` (with a foreach onto retrieved `foo` objects, as follows).

```
public updateFooRelated($foo_object_array) {
 foreach($foo_object_array as $foo) {
  $this->updateRelated($foo);
 }
}
```

Unfortunately, some `bar` objects of - call it - `foo1`  have the same `fooBar` object of other `bar` objects of - call it - `foo2` and this mess the things up because when i return to `updateRealted()` with the `foo2` object, I had already persisted `$bar` and this gave me the following error

> Exception caught: Entity of type
>   MyApplication\Entity\Bar
>   has identity through a foreign entity
>   MyApplication\Entity\FooBar, however
>   this entity has no identity itself. You have to call
>   EntityManager#persist() on the related entity and make sure that an
>   identifier was generated before trying to persist
>   'MyApplication\Entity\Bar'.
>   In case of Post Insert ID Generation (such as MySQL Auto-Increment or
>   PostgreSQL SERIAL) this means you have to call EntityManager#flush()
>   between both persist operations.

Of course if I do an `spl_object_has()` on various `fooBar` objects i get that, as predictable, some of them are the same object.

So, bonus question, what happens affter `persist()` to entity manager managed objects?

---

BTW, I suppose that fetch again `fooBar` object will be a solution, but how can i tell entity manager (in that case the repository) to give me another object so, basically, refetch it from db or make a copy of it an starts to manage?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having these problems, I would take advantage of the ManyToOne relation you have between Foo and Bars, I assume, and only use the Foo object to rerieve and update bars inside, which is automatically done by doctrine, if you use the "cascade persist" in the relation of your entity.